# I obtain a C project and got error when I do the command 'make elevator64' in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linker, ld

Hello I'm learning <**CSE 251 Programming in C**>  from webside [https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse251/project2.html](https://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Ecse251/project2.html).
I obtain the project and do the command 'make elevator64' in Ubuntu terminal.
But it failed. The error is below:

```
g++ -o elevator elevator.o -lm libElevatorLib64.a `wx-config --libs`
/usr/bin/ld: libElevatorLib64.a(ElevatorLib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: libElevatorLib64.a(CApp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: libElevatorLib64.a(CFrame.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `_ZN6CFrame13sm_eventTableE' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: 最后的链结失败: 输出不可表示的节
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'elevator64' failed
make: *** [elevator64] Error 1
```

What happens?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do the linker errors tell you what to do? They all give the same advice. Aside: I love the link's "If your code does not work correctly, you may kill someone or even burn the building down." As if burning the building is worse than killing people.

Comment: The three error messages tell you exactly what to do to fix the issue. Did you read the words in the message? They're not there just to take up screen space.

Comment: Was `libElevatorLib64.a` compiled by you, or given you to by someone?

Comment: but the libElevatorLib64.a is download from the website. I can't compile it

Comment: Then you should compile *your own* program without PIC. Can you modify the makefile or not?

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat he origin make file is: gcc -c -o elevator.o elevator.c                g++ -o elevator elevator.o -lm libElevatorLib64.a wx-config --libs           how to change it ?

Comment: After `elevator.c` add a space and `-fno-pic` (or `-fno-PIC`, not sure).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It doesnot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally builded the environment for  CSE-251-Programming-in-C labs and projects.
Here's my share: https://github.com/elivon2000/CSE-251-Programming-in-C

Answer (score 0):

> What happens?

You are trying to link your project with some pre-built library `libElevatorLib64.a`, which was built *without* `-fPIE`.

But your GCC is configured to produce `PIE` binaries by default, and can't use such a library.

To fix, ask your GCC to produce a non-PIE binary:

```
g++ -no-pie -o elevator elevator.o libElevatorLib64.a `wx-config --libs`
```